# How can I ignore spaces in a substring?

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I have a textbox that gives out suggestions based on user input and one of my textboxes is location based.

The problem is, if a user types in **Chicago,IL**, everything works, but if they type in **Chicago, IL**, the suggestions stop. The only difference between the two is the space after the comma.

How can I fix this, so that even if a user puts in 2 or 4 spaces after the comma it still shows the same results as the first case?

This is my code:

```
if (location.contains(",")) {
// the city works correctly
   String city = location.substring(0, location.indexOf(","));

   // state is the problem if the user puts any space after the comma
   // it throws everything off  
     String state = location.substring(location.indexOf(",") + 1);


  String myquery = "select * from zips where city ilike ? and state ilike ?";

  }
```

I have also tried this:

```
 String state = location.substring(location.indexOf(",".trim()) + 1);
```

The string variables are used to make calls to the database; that is why I have to eliminate any spaces.

Comment: try `String state = location.substring(location.indexOf(",") + 1).trim();`

Comment: Use state.trim() and city.trim()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I fix this, so that even if a user puts in 2 or 4 spaces after
>   the comma it still shows the same results as the first case?

you can use `location.replaceAll(" ", "")`

for extracting the location into `city,state`
you can use `split()` method as

`String location[]=location.split(",");`

Now

```
    String city=location[0];
    String state=location[1];
```

**EDIT:(for Whome)**

```
String location="New York, NY";
String loc[]=location.split(",");
String city=loc[0].trim();
String state=loc[1].trim();
System.out.println("City->"+city+"\nState->"+state);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is perfect

Comment: How about "New York,  NY"

Comment: @Whome check the EDIT.

Answer (score 2):

you were in the right direction by using trim(). However, you put it in the wrong place.
`",".trim()` will always yield `","`.   you want to trim the result of the substring operation:

```
String state = location.substring(location.indexOf(",") + 1).trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `java.lang.String` [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) function in the correct place.

trim on `",".trim()` will produce `","`.

Need to `trim()` the final result.

```
if (location.contains(",")) {
String city = location.substring(0, location.indexOf(",")).trim();
String state = location.substring(location.indexOf(",")).trim();
}
```

Comment: The definition of "trim" isn't valuable here since the OP has *some* idea as to what purpose it serves.  Rather, why don't you explain why you put the trim operation *there*?

Comment: Thanks a lot just did it and it worked, used trim on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Trim the entire result.  For example:

```
String city = (location.substring(0, location.indexOf(","))).trim();
String state = (location.substring(location.indexOf(",") + 1)).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String state = location.substring(location.indexOf(",") + 1).trim();
```

Instead of

```
String state = location.substring(location.indexOf(",".trim()) + 1);
```

That should work.